# problem with starting WAS in debug mode

Tags: debugging, websphere

I want to start my WAS server(on windows) in debug mode.But my application is huge and server time outs while starting in debugging mode.I have increased the timeout value to 1000 .What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

If you're running your server by using Rational Application Developer, it is possible that your server is basically waiting on a breakpoint. Sounds silly, but hey, happened to me a few times before.

If it's a regular installation:

- If it's a Network Deployment topology, make sure that the deployment manager and the node agent are up and running. Look at their log; they're often overlooked.
- If it's a single-server topology, then it's possible that your debug port (7777 by default) is in use. When that happens, the debugger process never quite "connects" to WebSphere.

To sum it up: it starts with the logs...

Answer (score 0):

Try changing connection settings on your server from using RMI to SOAP. If you are behind a firewall and you application is timing out on startup then it may help you. Also do you get any other information when the timeout occurs?